# SQL Table with two relations or table with one relation and repeated rows

Tags: mysql, sql

This is an example, the names are fictitious.

On the one hand, we have suppliers who provide products to shops:

**Suppliers**

```
id name

1  GreatSupplier
2  SuperSupplier
```

On the other hand, we have shops that sell products to consumers:

**Shops**

```
id name          supplier

1  NiceShop      null
2  ShopShop      null
3  Soop          1
4  CheapShop     1
5  MyShop        1
6  Shopping      2
```

There are shops that have their own prices like NiceShop or ShopShop, so they don't have suppliers. But there are shops that use the prices set by the supplier like Soop, CheapShop, MyShop or Shopping.

Then I want to show all the prices of the products that the shops show to their customers. Something like this:

```
NiceShop  - Tomate: 1.23      // shop price
ShopShop  - Tomate: 1.26      // shop price
Soop      - Tomate: 1.21      // supplier 1 price
CheapShop - Tomate: 1.21      // supplier 1 price
MyShop    - Tomate: 1.21      // supplier 1 price
Shopping  - Tomate: 1.19      // supplier 2 price
```

Two options come to mind:

***Option 1:***

**Products**

```
id id_product   id_shop   id_supplier   price
1  34           1         null         1.23
2  34           2         null         1.26
3  34           null      1            1.21
4  34           null      2            1.19
```

When displaying prices, if it is a row with `id_shop` I show it as is, but if it is a row with `id_supplier` I join the supplier and the shops.

Here I can't make a unique index between `id_product-id_store-id_supplier` and things like this could happen:

```
id id_product   id_shop   id_supplier   price
5  34           3         null          1.21 // wrong
```

This should not happen as shop 3 has supplier 1 and this is already inserted in id 3.

***Option 2:***

Another option would be:

- If we insert a price from a shop that does not have a supplier, it is inserted as is.
- If we insert a price from a supplier, a join is made between the supplier and the shops and the same price is inserted several times. (same for updates)

**Products**

```
id id_product   id_shop   price

1  34           1         1.23      // shop price
2  34           2         1.26      // shop price
3  34           3         1.21      // supplier 1 price
4  34           4         1.21      // supplier 1 price
5  34           5         1.21      // supplier 1 price
5  34           6         1.19      // supplier 2 price
```

This option is a bit cleaner and allows me to create a single `id_product-id_shop` index but I am creating a **lot of records with repeated prices**, in this example it is duplicated 3 times but in my real environment it can be duplicated 50 times, and that translates into several extra gigabytes of database space.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If a shop can have more than one supplier, please change the example data.

Comment: @RickJames a shop can't have more than one supplier but one product can have several suppliers. With what you said about setting the suppliers to 0, I don't know how I can differentiate between different suppliers for the same product, maybe I didn't understand your idea, if you can develop it a little bit it would be ideal.

Comment: What if you treated each shop that supplies itself as its own supplier? So the 'suppliers' table would have all the suppliers, and shops that are their own supplier. A relationship between `shops (id, name, supplier_id), suppliers (id, name), and prices (id, product_id, supplier_id, price)` could then be understood.

Comment: @BeRT2me while that would work to solve the querying issues described by OP, it's likely to cause confusion down the line to have entities in the suppliers table that are not actually suppliers; e.g.: columns/keys/indices on suppliers that are not used for the shops; or if additional tables are made with a FK to suppliers, but they're only relevant to suppliers that are not shops; or if an application needs to render the list of suppliers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the issues described can be solved by creating a common associated table for both `shops` and `suppliers` that is used to associate prices. In my example, I'll call this the `price_setters` table.

A Shop's Price-Setter is either itself or its supplier. This is enforced by the constraint on `price_setters` that the record has either a unique `shop_id` or a unique `supplier_id`, but not both.

`prices` has a FK to `price_setters` rather than `shops` or `suppliers`.

The only "anomaly" remaining is that there is no requirement in the schema for a shop or supplier to have a price_setter; however, that would just prevent you from assigning prices to the entity.

*Edit: I moved the FKs between price_setters, shops, and suppliers into price_setters*

```sql
-- Retrieve all prices by shop by going through the price_setter

select 
  shops.name,
  products.name,
  prices.price
from shops
left join suppliers 
  on shops.supplier_id = suppliers.id
join price_setters 
  on shops.id = price_setters.shop_id 
  or suppliers.id = price_setters.supplier_id
join prices 
  on prices.price_setter_id = price_setters.id
join products 
  on prices.product_id = products.id
;

create table suppliers (
  id unsigned bigint primary key, 
  name varchar(255) not null
);

create table shops (
  id unsigned bigint primary key,
  name varchar(255) not null,
  supplier_id unsigned bigint,
  FOREIGN KEY (supplier_id) REFERENCES suppliers(id)
);

create table products (
  id unsigned bigint primary key,
  name varchar(255) not null
);

-- A shop's price setter is either itself or its supplier
create table price_setters (
  id unsigned bigint primary key,
  shop_id unsigned bigint ,
  supplier_id unsigned bigint,
  FOREIGN KEY (shop_id) REFERENCES shops(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (supplier_id) REFERENCES suppliers(id),
  unique(shop_id),
  unique(supplier_id),
  CONSTRAINT chk_shop_xor_supplier CHECK (
    (shop_id IS NOT NULL AND supplier_id IS NULL)
        OR (shop_id IS NULL AND supplier_id IS NOT NULL)
  )
);

create table prices (
  id unsigned bigint primary key,
  product_id unsigned bigint not null,
  price_setter_id unsigned bigint not null,
  price float not null,
  unique(product_id, price_setter_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (price_setter_id) REFERENCES price_setters(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products(id)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have it clean you will need 3 entities (apart from shops and suppliers):

**Products** (PK = id_product)

```
id_product   name (and other attributes)
34           Tomate
```

**Shop prices** (PK = id_product + id_shop)

```
id_product   id_shop   price
34           1         1.23
34           2         1.26
```

**Supplier prices** (PK = id_product + id_supplier)

```
id_product   id_supplier   price
34           1             1.21
34           2             1.19
```

In both shop prices and supplier prices product/shop/supplier ids are not null and foreign keys to corresponding tables.

To display a list you will need to union both price tables:

```
SELECT s.id as id_shop, shp.id_product, shp.price
  FROM shops s
  JOIN shop_prices shp ON (shp.id_shop = s.id AND s.supplier_id IS NULL)
 UNION ALL
SELECT s.id as id_shop, sup.id_product, sup.price
  FROM shops s
  JOIN supplier_prices sup ON (sup.id_supplier = s.id_supplier)
```

(+extra joins with products if you need to display product attributes like name...)

This structure can't prevent eg. adding a record to shop prices for a shop that has a supplier, as in your example:

```
id_product   id_shop   price
34           3         1.21
```

But if you're careful such record wouldn't even show, for example in query above it is filtered out with `s.supplier_id IS NULL` in join condition. If it's mandatory, such case can be caught in a trigger or just at application level.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just add shops without suppliers to the suppliers table?
Also - this phrase scares me:

> bit complicated to maintain in the updates

I would use views to display the prices - not new tables.

I would also consider adding some form of versioning to your product/price table. Two ways to do this: add  `begin_ts` and `end_ts` where end_ts = '9999-12-31' means the record is still active. Or alternatively, have a trigger that automatically tracks when a record changes and writes the record to an archive table. Bottom line is you will probably want something that tracks the price history so you can show what the prices where X days, weeks, months, years ago.